# The reason and meaning of repeating

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

In the movie "My Fair Lady", the main character will use this structure a lot; "I'm a good girl, I am." or "I washed my face and hands before I come, I did.".
I like to know more about this structure and when such thing can be used.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This repetition acts much like an exclamation mark to insist on the truth of what has gone before.

It should not be emulated, unless you are aiming at a comic effect. Note that Eliza Dolittle comes to Prof. Higgins to lose her vernacular usage:

> I want to be a lady in a flower shop stead of sellin at the corner of Tottenham Court Road. But they wont take me unless I can talk more genteel.

That gentility, as she learns in Act III, is not merely a matter of pronouncing words properly. She must also master the terms and phrases and syntax of "proper" English. One of the vernacular tricks she loses is just this insistent repetition: it disappears after Act II and does not return until Act V, at the precise moment when Eliza realizes her true strength and taunts Higgins by deliberately reverting for *a single sentence* to her old way of speech:

> Thats done you, Enry Iggins, it az.

That sentence is the climax of the entire play, but the form of expression is ironic. I presume that you, like Eliza, want to employ "proper" English, not the street speech of 1913. If so, avoid this use.

---

The quotations above are from the text of Shaw's *Pygmalion*; I don't know whether they're preserved in the script of the musical and the movie.

Comment: I like "This repetition acts much like an exclamation mark to insist on the truth of what has gone before." Which makes it a pragmatic marker (emphasis - to the addressee, perhaps partly to convince oneself; there may also be a 'speech facilitator' role, giving the speaker time to marshall subsequent statements).

Comment: Oh, and is there an echo of Sherlock (_Sherlock: A Study in Pink_) in the scarified "proper"? We'll get _him_ to decide when CGEL overstep the mark.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The quotes are actually ironic, recalling Dolittle's plaint after he becomes rich: " I'll have to learn to speak middle class language from you, instead of speaking proper English." I'm afraid the *Sherlock* allusion escapes me; these days I watch television only for baseball, election results, and tornado warnings. :)

Comment: In that case, I'd say the _Sherlock_ (which I can't recommend highly enough - treat yourself - best drama I've seen in many a year) usage is itself an intentional echo of Shaw. (In a sub-sub-plot in another episode, SH seems to leave one obvious murderer to his fate, instead of querying the evidence, because his grammar is so poor.)